# How do we handle RC versioning in php composer projects

Tags: php, composer-php

Here's the scenario:

- 'Main repository' has a package, `test/my-package` set to version `^4.0.0`
- If I understand correctly, that will pull anything like `v4.0.0`, `v4.0.0-rc.1` etc
- `test/my-package` is currently set at `v4.0.0-rc.1`
- `composer.lock` for 'Main repository' is locked at the commit for `v4.0.0-rc.1`

In testing, the need to make changes and fixes arises often, and therefore causes a release of a new rc: `v4.0.0-rc.2`.

The question is, with 'Main repository' composer.lock being locked at the commit for `v4.0.0-rc.1`, how should the need to deploy the dependency update to `v4.0.0-rc.2` be handled in practice? Obviously the code needs updating, but it is bad practice to pull updated dependencies for all packages into a deployment of 'Main repository'?

Answer (score 0):

You can just update the `test/my-package` to the new version by running `composer update test/my-package`. This should not touch any other dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is simple when we know what packages need updating. I was hoping to find an answer that would not need to update the 'Main repository', as though we could not record the commit of specific packages in the lock file for example. It seems like a dependency inversion problem that I have to alter one package because one of it's dependencies is altered.

Comment: That's not possible I'm afraid. The point of the lock file is to hold the exact versions to install, so you need to update the main repository, there's no way around it.